# Join two dataframes based on closest combination that sums up to a target value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-itertools

Im trying to join below two dataframes based on closest combination of rows from **df2** column `Sales` that sums up to target value in **df1** column `Total Sales`, columns `Name` & `Date` in both dataframes should be the same when joining (as showed in expected output).

For Example : in **df1** row number 0 should be matched only with **df2** rows 0 & 1, since columns `Name` & `Date` is the same, Which is Name : John and Date : 2021-10-01.

**df1 :**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":{"0":"John","1":"John","2":"Jack","3":"Nancy","4":"Ahmed"},
                    "Date":{"0":"2021-10-01","1":"2021-11-01","2":"2021-10-10","3":"2021-10-12","4":"2021-10-30"},
                    "Total Sales":{"0":15500,"1":5500,"2":17600,"3":20700,"4":12000}})

    Name    Date        Total Sales
0   John    2021-10-01  15500
1   John    2021-11-01  5500
2   Jack    2021-10-10  17600
3   Nancy   2021-10-12  20700
4   Ahmed   2021-10-30  12000
```

**df2 :**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":{"0":"JO1","1":"JO2","2":"JO3","3":"JO4","4":"JA1","5":"JA2","6":"NA1",
                          "7":"NA2","8":"NA3","9":"NA4","10":"AH1","11":"AH2","12":"AH3","13":"AH3"},
                    "Name":{"0":"John","1":"John","2":"John","3":"John","4":"Jack","5":"Jack","6":"Nancy","7":"Nancy",
                            "8":"Nancy","9":"Nancy","10":"Ahmed","11":"Ahmed","12":"Ahmed","13":"Ahmed"},
                    "Date":{"0":"2021-10-01","1":"2021-10-01","2":"2021-11-01","3":"2021-11-01","4":"2021-10-10","5":"2021-10-10","6":"2021-10-12","7":"2021-10-12",
                            "8":"2021-10-12","9":"2021-10-12","10":"2021-10-30","11":"2021-10-30","12":"2021-10-30","13":"2021-10-29"},
                    "Sales":{"0":10000,"1":5000,"2":1000,"3":5500,"4":10000,"5":7000,"6":20000,
                             "7":100,"8":500,"9":100,"10":5000,"11":7000,"12":10000,"13":12000}})

    ID  Name    Date        Sales
0   JO1 John    2021-10-01  10000
1   JO2 John    2021-10-01  5000
2   JO3 John    2021-11-01  1000
3   JO4 John    2021-11-01  5500
4   JA1 Jack    2021-10-10  10000
5   JA2 Jack    2021-10-10  7000
6   NA1 Nancy   2021-10-12  20000
7   NA2 Nancy   2021-10-12  100
8   NA3 Nancy   2021-10-12  500
9   NA4 Nancy   2021-10-12  100
10  AH1 Ahmed   2021-10-30  5000
11  AH2 Ahmed   2021-10-30  7000
12  AH3 Ahmed   2021-10-30  10000
13  AH3 Ahmed   2021-10-29  12000
```

**Expected Output :**

```
    Name    Date        Total Sales Comb IDs            Comb Total
0   John    2021-10-01  15500       JO1, JO2            15000.0
1   John    2021-11-01  5500        JO4                 5500.0
2   Jack    2021-10-10  17600       JA1, JA2            17000.0
3   Nancy   2021-10-12  20700       NA1, NA2, NA3, NA4  20700.0
4   Ahmed   2021-10-30  12000       AH1, AH2            12000.0
```

What i have tried below is working for only one row at a time, but im not sure how to apply it in pandas dataframes to get the expected output.

Variable `numbers` in below script represent `Sales` column in **df2**, and variable `target` below represent `Total Sales` column in **df1**.

```
import itertools
import math

numbers = [1000, 5000, 3000]
target = 6000

best_combination = ((None,))
best_result = math.inf
best_sum = 0

for L in range(0, len(numbers)+1):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(numbers, L):
        sum = 0
        for number in combination:
            sum += number
        result = target - sum
        if abs(result) < abs(best_result):
            best_result = result
            best_combination = combination
            best_sum = sum

print("\nbest sum{} = {}".format(best_combination, best_sum))


[Out] best sum(1000, 5000) = 6000
```

Comment: You should look to `knapsack problem`.

Comment: It seems in the most general case, for each person and date, you have an optimisation problem where you have to select a subset of a set of numbers, to try and minimise the difference between sum and a target.  This is similar to the knapsack problem.  It's not trivial to get an optimal answer unless your problems are small enough to brute force, but even then I doubt you will get an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the code you wrote which finds the best sum and turn it into a function (let's call it `opt`, which has parameters for target and a dataframe (which will be a subset of `df2`.  It needs to return a list of IDs which correspond to the optimal combination.

Write another function which takes 3 arguments name, date and target (let's call it `calc`).   This function will filter `df2` based on name and date, and pass it, along with the target to the `opt` function and return the result of that function.  Finally, iterate through rows of `df1`, and call `calc` with the row arguments (or alternatively use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`